# compiling for debu and relates nods

Tags: c#

Good day for all
in the middle of my application
I have 2 sections code
I want one to be completed for debug and not for released moded
and the second in a reverse manner

how I do setup this in visual studio

currently I achieved this by keeping 2 copies
of my application one copy with code commented
for debug mode and the other copy with code
commented for released mofe

thank you.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation

Answer (score 0):

You can use preprocessor directives like so:

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Compiles when debug is configured");
#endif
//...
#if(!DEBUG)
    Console.WriteLine("Compiles otherwise");
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you very much I was thinking that this should be at top of the program

Comment: when you always see black horses you come to think that there isn't a white horse